# Ratios in big-O notation?

Tags: asymptotics, discrete-mathematics

Hi can anyone give me a counter example of the following claim:

```
f(n) = O(s(n)) and g(n)=O(r(n)) imply f(n)/g(n) = O(s(n)/r(n))
```

Thank you

Comment: This is a question from my algorithm text book. So far I just assume there might be a way on the left side to cancel out the critical terms by dividing, but the right side can keep what ever it is. But I couldn't come up with a complete solution to it. @templatetypedef

Comment: Hi Allan Jiang.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, the current accepted answer is completely correct.  What kind of answer are you looking for with the bounty?

Comment: One that satisfies Allan Jiang.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, if Allan Jiang would say how that answer does not satisfy him then a more appropriate one could be given.

Comment: No problem. :D ..

Comment: Can some one find an exception for big Theta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy.

Let $f(n) = n^2 = O(n^2)$ and $g(n) = n = O(n^2)$. And we get $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = n$ which is not in the set $O(\frac{n^2}{n^2}) = O(1)$.

Why $n=O(n^2)$? Because there exists a positive constant number $M=1$ and a real number $n_0=1$, such that $|n| \leq M|n^2|$, for all $n > n_0$.

Comment: Given how clear it's been made that this is (a) a homework problem and (b) the OP hasn't made any apparent attempt to solve it themselves, rewarding their laziness by providing the answer is... unfortunate.

Comment: I feel so sorry... I'm fresh here, and I just answered this question as soon as I saw it and I did not think more.

Comment: That's fair - and I apologize if my tone was harsh; this scenario just tends to happen a lot. Please don't be discouraged from contributing in future. :)

Answer (score 4):

As a hint, remember that big-O is *not* a tight bound.  Could you make $r(n)$ grow much more rapidly than $g(n)$, such that $O\left( \frac{s(n)}{r(n)}\right)$ ends up being much smaller than $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$?

Hope this helps!